# Validate image input works unexpected... / Nextjs Server Actions- Zod

Tags: reactjs, next.js, zod

I have zod validation schema like this...

```
export const newProductSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(2, 'Minimum 2 chars.').max(15, 'Maximum 15 chars.'),
  image: z
    .any()
    .refine(
      (files) => files?.[0]?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE,
      `Max image size is 5MB.`
    )
    .refine(
      (files) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(files?.[0]?.type),
      'Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp formats are supported.'
    )
    .optional(),
});
```

But when i upload a simple png (45kb) it throws error first error 'Max image size is 5MB'

If i remove first validation, it throws second validation error 'Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp formats are supported.'

In summary it always returns error

```
export const MAX_FILE_SIZE =  1024 * 1024 * 5;
export const ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES = [
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/jpg',
  'image/png',
  'image/webp',
];
```

Comment: I think the files size that you are sending for the condition is in `Bytes` which you have to convert it to `MB` in order to meet the condition as follow: `(files?.[0]?.size / Math.pow(1024,2)) <= MAX_FILE_SIZE`

Comment: @OnlyMAJ Ive tried it yet it returns first validation error all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the scenario where the `files` is an array with a file object is not properly handled. The `refine` method is checking the first file in the `files` array, but the issue might be with how the file is being passed to the validation schema.

Ensure that the file is passed as an array to the schema and that the file object has the `size` and `type` properties. If these properties are not present or the file is not passed in an array, the validation errors you're seeing would occur.

Verify that the `type` property of the file object matches one of the accepted MIME types in `ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES`.

Also if `files` is `undefined` or not an array, the `files?.[0]?.size` and `files?.[0]?.type` will not work as expected and will cause the validation to fail.

I modified your schema:

```
import { z } from 'zod';

export const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
export const ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES = [
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/jpg',
  'image/png',
  'image/webp',
];

export const newProductSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(2, 'Minimum 2 chars.').max(15, 'Maximum 15 chars.'),
  image: z
    .array(
      z.object({
        size: z.number(),
        type: z.string(),
      })
    )
    .optional()
    .refine(
      (files) => files?.[0]?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE,
      `Max image size is 5MB.`
    )
    .refine(
      (files) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(files?.[0]?.type),
      'Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp formats are supported.'
    ),
});
```